# You'll keep this live

Tags: sentence-meaning

A quote from the Inception movie:

> Cobb: Fischer, you'll be going with him.
>
> Fischer: All right. What
>   about you?
>
> Cobb: *You keep this live.* I'll be listening for the whole
>   time.

What does *you keep this live* mean in that context? Fischer asked about what route Cobb was going go by and to me, the answer as *You keep this live* seems a bit unclear in the context. Couldn't you explain that?

Comment: 'keep it online' or 'keep your communication line open all the time' We would need to know more context to be specific, but that's the general idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're talking about a communications device or a tracking device. Fischer (or the other person) is to keep a microphone on or "live" so that Cobb can hear what's happening or follow their progress. I haven't seen the movie so I can't be specific.

You'll often hear about flubs by on-air presenters because they forget that their mic is live aka transmitting.